# sending url in ajax jquery and getting response null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have client URL and getting response from that URL through browser. While sending through AJAX I am getting a null response. Right now I am working with a .Net application. Here I am given my script. Please guide me to get proper response and thanks in advance.

Response:

```
{
    "resultFlag": false,
    "message": "Dealer not found",
    "info": []
}
```

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: URL,
    //data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
    success: function (result) {
        // JSON.stringify(result);
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
    }    
});
```

Comment: Since you're using `GET`, can you run the server-side code by pasting the URL into a browser and see what response you get there?

Comment: When you debug this in the browser's debugging tools, what is the server's response?  Is the server also something you can debug?

Comment: The call is to the same domain as the page is hosted on?

Comment: while debug I am getting the server response is null.